# grep the lines of unknown word

Tags: linux, grep

I am able to grep using command

```
grep "HTTP/1.0\" | 404 "
```

Similarly how can I grep all other 404 errors. I mean the the values of 1.0 within the **HTTP/1.0** changes everytime, so how to grep all the HTTP/* .

I have tried

```
grep "HTTP/*\" | 404 "
```

But no use. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: grep uses regular expressions, so instead of `grep "HTTP/*\" | 404 "` you should write `grep "HTTP/.*\" | 404 "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's have a try

```
grep "HTTP/.* 404"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do not want to use regex and backslashes, you can use dots:

```
echo 'HTTP/1.0" 404' | grep "HTTP/.... 404"
```

I think you can find a lot scripts for parsing your access.log. I just found [nginx parsing](https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/nginx/log-parsing/).

Comment: Ok. I wanted to write a simple form of regex, but a regex with a backslash is still simple. So I tried to explain it as a regex with a backslash, but should have written `with`.